# Floating numbers instead of fractions in Sympy Matrices?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a converging iterative solver that makes use of Sympy Matrices. The output is a matrix.

The problem is that the entries in the matrix output are always fractions. So after each iteration, as the solution converges and becomes more accurate, I end up with fractions with absurdly large denominator and numerators.

e.g.
11143995411559850973776170460385167311/3964268449063394905829715776718192855 = ~2.81

Is there a Sympy command to force floating point numbers instead of fractions?

Answer (score 0):

Found out sympy has a simple method that can be applied to the entire matrix to get floating numbers:

```python
.evalf()

SomeDumbMatrix.evalf()
```